# OpenDocumentXML Excel exponentitally slows when inserting cell sharedstringtable values

Tags: c#, excel, linq, openxml

The standard approach in code samples is to iterate the sharedstringtable seraching for the value to be added. Add; if not found and use existing if the string exists. However, this searching slows dramatically after a couple of hundred values.

I used a LINQ query to search for the string and it appears faster. See commented out lines in the code. However, I could not determine the position of the found item. Does anyone know a method to identify the location of an item in a sharedstring table.

```
        public static int InsertSharedStringItem(string text, InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet mySpreadsheet)
    {
        // If the part does not contain a SharedStringTable, create one.
        if (mySpreadsheet.sharedstringtable == null)
        {
            mySpreadsheet.shareStringPart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        }

        //SharedStringItem item = mySpreadsheet.sharedstringtable.Elements<SharedStringItem>()
        //            .Where(t => t.InnerText == text)
        //            .FirstOrDefault();
        //if(item != null)
        //{
        //    return item's location in the shared string table;
        //}

        // Iterate through all the items in the SharedStringTable. If the text already exists, return its index.
        int i = 0;
        foreach (SharedStringItem item1 in mySpreadsheet.sharedstringtable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (item1.InnerText == text)
            {
                return i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index.
        mySpreadsheet.sharedstringtable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(text)));
        return i;
    }
```

A sharedstringtable value is added using:

```
                index = InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet.InsertSharedStringItem(string.IsNullOrEmpty(datarow.AssignedTo) ? string.Empty : datarow.AssignedTo, myspreadsheet);
            // Insert cell into the new worksheet.
            cell = InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet.InsertCellInWorksheet(InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet.GetExcelColumnName(colAddr++), rowAddr, myspreadsheet.worksheetPart.Worksheet);
            // Set the value of cell.
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(index.ToString());
            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
```

To limit the problem, I use a non-shared string approach for cells where matches have a low probability. I use this code:

```
                Cell cell = InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet.InsertCellInWorksheet(InfoReg.OpenXML.Spreadsheet.GetExcelColumnName(colAddr++), rowAddr, myspreadsheet.worksheetPart.Worksheet);
            // Set the value of cell.
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(datarow.ForeName);
            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
```

Some articles suggested using a Dictionary<string, int> with a copy of the shared string table. I did not see any significant improvement in performance with the Dictionary.

Comment: What happens if you insert in reverse order? Often, in cases of non-constant insert behaviour, this helps. But possibly not this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing with the Lazy(Dictionary.. in the jAnderson answer, I found the dictionary never got populated. I am not familiar with Lazy and may have done something wrong. My thanks again to jAnderson whose answer provided a clear path to a working solution.

The code below offers significant performance improvements on the standard iteration approach documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-shared-string-table.

The modified wrapper class uses a dictionary to initially mirror the shared string table and as new entries are added to the table, they are also added to the dictionary. Thus, one can search the dictionary to find an existing entry rather than iterating through the shared string table.

Some of our data is incomplete. Nulls and empty strings are encountered regularly. Thus, the addition of a null test and a fast path to returning an empty string entry from the SharedStringTable.

While this is a massive improvement, the internal management of the SharedStringTable could do with some binary indexing or similar more scalable solution.

The modified wrapper class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace MyOpenXML
{
    public class SharedStringWrapper
    {
        private readonly SharedStringTable _table;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _dict;
        private int _maxElement;
        private int _emptyStringElement;

        public SharedStringWrapper(SharedStringTable table)
        {
            _table = table; // Gets the table as is in the spreadsheet
            _maxElement = _table.Elements().Count(); // Count of elements at the start
            _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // Shadow copy of the shared string table
            int i = 0;
            foreach (SharedStringItem item in _table.Elements<SharedStringItem>()) // _dict is given its initial copy
            {
                _dict.Add(item.InnerText, i++);
            }
            // Add an empty string entry if one does not exist.
            _emptyStringElement = _maxElement;
            try
            {
                _emptyStringElement = _dict[string.Empty];  // Used for fast location of empty string value
            }
            catch
            {
                _table.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(string.Empty)));
                _dict.Add(string.Empty, _maxElement++);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts text into the shared string table and returns the index of the inserted text.
        /// If the text already exists, it returns the index of the existing element.
        /// Also inserts a copy in _dict so that it is a copy of the shared string table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">text to insert</param>
        /// <returns>index of the element in the shared strings table</returns>
        public int InsertTextElement(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return _emptyStringElement; // Treat null as empty string
            int indx = _maxElement; // Value for new entry
            try
            {
                indx = _dict[text]; // If the text is found the index is to be returned
            }
            catch // An entry has not been found, add it to both the shared string table and the dictionary
            {
                //append child and increment the count.
                _table.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
                _dict.Add(text, _maxElement++);
            }
            return indx; // return index.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The idea with the Dictionary should give you better performance, but if you're recreating the dictionary every time you want to insert an element, you won't save any time, in fact it'll only take longer.

The way I see it is to wrap the SharedStringTable in a wrapper which caches and keeps track of the elements and make sure that the wrapper is the ONLY way you access the shared string table.

```
public class SharedStringWrapper
{
    private readonly SharedStringTable _table;
    private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, (int index, OpenXmlElement element)>> _lazyDict;
    private int _maxElement;

    public SharedStringWrapper(SharedStringTable table)
    {
        _table = table;

        _maxElement = _table.Elements().Count();
        //lazy initialize, this could take a while, no reason to do it until we need it.
        //in this case we ignore the casing of the text
        _lazyDict = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, (int index, OpenXmlElement element)>>(
            _table.Select((element, index) => (element, index)).ToDictionary(k => k.element.InnerText, v => (v.index, itm: v.element)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts text into the shared string table and returns the index of the inserted text.
    /// If the text already exists, it returns the index of the existing element
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">text to insert</param>
    /// <returns>index of the element in the shared strings table</returns>
    public int InsertTextElement(string text)
    {
        //this is where you get the huge time saving - first time it will take a while, subsequently it'll be way faster
        if (_lazyDict.Value.TryGetValue(text, out var value))
            return value.index;

        //append child and increment the count.
        _table.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
        _maxElement++;

        return _maxElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can see your answer will achieve the objective. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome - if it solved your issue please mark it as answered :)

Comment: The answer did not work because strings were never matched. However, I used the ideas suggests with some minor changes and I have a working solution. I add an entry for an empty string and force any nulls to empty string. This makes the solution more robust. Performance still slows but the speeds are acceptable upto around 10,000 rows.